# Why compare operator <,>,= given wrong output when comparing strings?

Tags: c++, string, string-comparison, comparison-operators

I am comparing two string using comparison operators(<,>,=).

The output of "a" < "b" In this case is 0.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<("a" < "a")<<endl;
    cout<<("b" < "a")<<endl;
    cout<<("a" < "b")<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

outputs -

```
0
1
0
```

But why the output is changing when i am comparing only "a" < "b" ?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    // cout<<("a" < "a")<<endl;
    // cout<<("b" < "a")<<endl;
    cout<<("a" < "b")<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output -
`1`

Here are the SS-

[1st output]https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHqzM.png

[2nd output]https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrUEx.png

I have so confused right now !! pls anyone can assist me with this

Comment: you are not comparing strings, you are comparing arrays which decay to pointers

Comment: strings in c++ are `std::string`. `std::string("a") < std::string("b")` you want

Comment: do not ignore compiler warnings ! https://godbolt.org/z/qjWx6Mx84 !

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai C-style strings remain part of C++.  In fact arguably more so than `std::string` which is part of the library, while support for literal string constants as in this example is _built-in_.

Comment: In an expression a literal string constant has type `const char*` - you are comparing pointers, not strings.  C-style strings are not data types.  Use `std::strcmp()` or the `std::string` class for which these operators have overloads.

Comment: Or `cout<<("a"s < "b"s)<<endl;` to compare strings.  Note the `s` suffix. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s

Comment: `"a" < "b"` compares the address of the first character in both string literals.  Since the layout of string literals in memory is unspecified, there is no guarantee of what the comparison will produce.    If you want to do lexicographic comparison (which will compare characters in the string individually) either use `std::strcmp("a", "b")` (which produces a negative value for "less than", zero for equal, and a positive value for "greater than") or use `std::string`  (e.g. `std::string("a") < std::string("b")`) or (since C++11) `std::string` literals (e.g. `"a"s < "b"s`).

Answer (score 2):

You are not comparing [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) objects with well defined inequality operations. You are comparing [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) with unspecified memory locations. Therefore `<` will not return what you expect:

> The type of an unprefixed string literal is `const char[N]`, where N is the size of the string [..], including the null terminator.

Comment: Ah ... the meaning of comparing string literals has well-defined inequality operations.   It is comparing the address of the first character of each (statically allocated) string literal.     The *result* of the comparison is unspecified (since the layout in memory is unspecified).

Comment: @Peter Yep, as I say, the memory location is unspecified. Therefore the result is not what OP was expecting.